# How do I customize the ellipsis on a truncated UILabel?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel

A [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) will truncate text that is too long to fit and append ellipsis to the end:

> Very long sentence in small UILa...

How do I customize the ellipsis text? I want to use `..."` instead of just `...`. My use case is quoted text such as:

> John Smith said, "Hello, Jane Doe".

It is being truncated to:

> John Smith said, "Hello, Jane D...

I think it would look better as:

> John Smith said, "Hello, Jane ..."